# CKEditor autogrow plugin not working for editor in different tabs

Tags: ckeditor

I am having number of CKEditors on my page under different tabs (having fieldset) and using autogrow plugin. but plugin does not seems to work for all the editor except the editor those falls under focused tab. I have added below lines.

`config.autoGrow_onStartup = true;
 config.extraPlugins = 'autogrow';
 config.removePlugins = 'resize';`

But when i click on editor after changing the tab, autogrow plugin resizes the editor correctly.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your code .

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('.textarea');
```

Comment: I am already using `CKEDITOR.replaceAll(function(textarea, config) {});`

Comment: Have you added the script?

Comment: Yes. I have added.